# Linux Shell for Low Latency

Tags: linux, latency, algorithmic-trading

My research far shows that Linux is more used in low latency/high frequency trading software. Just wanted to know which shell is used in Linux for such kind of applications. Bash or ksh or any other ? And what is the reason for any specific shell ?

Many Thanks for your help on this.

-Nishant.

Comment: You don't use a shell for low-latency work.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on the question correctly points out, the question is not which Linux **shell** is best suited to high frequency trading, I *think* you mean **kernel**.

It is my understanding there is not hard and fast answer to this, as there are many aspects to it such as hardware and type of systems which will be run to perform the high frequency trading. E.g. How are you managing data streams, message between threads, how is the business logic structured etc.

This blog post series is very useful and will point you on the right direction: 
http://blog.kreyolys.com/2011/03/05/kernel-performance-tuning-is-art-not-science-part-1/